# Are inout variables of protocol type prohibited?

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7-beta5

The following code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {}

private func doSomethingWith(inout someVar: SomeProtocol) {}

private var someGlobalVar = SomeClass() // inferring SomeClass's type

doSomethingWith(&someGlobalVar)
```

produces the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'doSomethingWith' with an argument list of type '(inout SomeClass)'

Changing the penultimate line to `private var someGlobalVar: SomeProtocol = SomeClass()` resolves the error.

Subj.

Comment: I'm surprised this question does not have more views! It seems like something more people would run into...then again, maybe people aren't mutating objects through functions with protocol parameters any more. :)

Comment: @RayToal perhaps that's because `inout` variables isn't so popular choice when designing your architecture ;)

Comment: True, and it's for the better. The class-only protocol solves this problem beautifully, but it's not obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a `SomeClass` instance to a variable while declaring, the variable type is inferred to be `SomeClass`. The same as writing

```
private var someGlobalVar: SomeClass = SomeClass()
```

However, when passing to an `inout` parameter, the function can assign another instance to that variable, e.g.

```
private func doSomethingWith(inout someVar: SomeProtocol) {
    someVar = OtherClass()
}
```

Now you have a type mismatch. The error you are seeing is Swift preventing you getting a similar problem.

In other words: if you are passing a variable to a function and you know that the function can assign any instance adopting `SomeProtocol` to that variable, you have to use a variable that can actually hold any instance adopting `SomeProtocol`:

```
private var someGlobalVar: SomeProtocol
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @Sulthan said, there are two more possible solutions,
depending on what your function needs to do.

You can make the function *generic*:

```
func doSomethingWith<T : SomeProtocol>(inout someVar: T) {}
```

Now you can pass an instance of any class conforming to the protocol:

```
var someGlobalVar = SomeClass()
doSomethingWith(&someGlobalVar)
```

If you only work with instances of a *class* and the function only
modifies properties of the object pointed-to by the instance, then you don't need an inout-parameter at all, since classes are reference types.
You only need to mark the protocol as a "class protocol":

```
protocol SomeProtocol : class {
    var name : String { get set }
}
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    var name : String = ""
}

func doSomethingWith(someVar: SomeProtocol) {
    // Modify the object:
    someVar.name = "modfied"
}

var someGlobalVar = SomeClass()
doSomethingWith(someGlobalVar)
print(someGlobalVar.name) // "modified"
```