# Why does my Xcode compiler tell me I use a value type even though I use classes?

Tags: ios, swift, class, reference, inout

I have two `classes`: Player and Enemy that both conform to the `protocol` CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol:

```
class Enemy: CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol {...
class Player: CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol {...
```

They are both `references` and not `values` like `structs` are; still when I send in the `objects` as arguments like this:

```
viewModel.combatButtonIsClicked(attacker: self.player, defender: self.enemy) { result in...
```

I get the error

> Passing value of type 'CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol' to an inout parameter requires explicit '&'

Why is this showing up? Isn't this only supposed to happen with `structs`?

If I do as the compiler wish and inset `inout` and `&` at the appropriate places things work except for in closures where the error now is

> Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'characterVM'

Here's where it happens (just for completion):

```
func enemyTurn(enemyVM: CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol, characterVM: inout CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol, completion: @escaping(_ enemyReponse: String) -> Void){
    let xEnemy = enemyVM.getX()
    let yEnemy = enemyVM.getY()
        
    viewModel.enemyShouldMove = true

    viewModel.proximityCheck(checkProxyForWho: .enemy, i: xEnemy, j: yEnemy, completion: {
        let combat = Combat()
        combat.combat(attacker: enemyVM, defender: &characterVM, completion: { result in...
```

I have searched on how to solve this error and the get the following suggestion: "change the struct to a class"...

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31960117/1187415 – you probably want to declare CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol as a “class protocol”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your protocol class bound? If not, the compiler needs to assume that a `struct` may also implement it and needs to apply value semantics.
To make a protocol class bound you simply need to do like this:
`protocol CharacterCharacteristicsProtocol: class`

Then you will only be able to implement it with classess, and not structs, and the compiler will be able to assume that only reference semantics apply.

Comment: Just a minor side note: `: class` is considered less favorable; `: AnyObject` is a preferred way to limit a protocol adoption to class types.

Comment: @Losiowaty Ah, ok, I didn't know that. So even though you only use classes you specifically need to resdtrict the protocol. Thanks a bunch for clearing that up!

Comment: @VadimBelyaev Ok, good to know! Could you just elaborate a bit on why it is more favorable to use AnyObject. And doesn't AnyObject incluce structs as well?

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt, the `: class` is no longer mentioned in the official Swift documentation therefore I'd speculate it may be deprecated eventually. There's a subtle difference between `: class` and `: AnyObject` as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176814/whats-the-difference-between-a-protocol-extended-from-anyobject-and-a-class-onl/32895975#32895975

In practice the two will have identical behavior in most cases.

A struct can't conform to `AnyObject` (compiler will raise an error), therefore a struct can't conform to a class-only protocol declared with `: AnyObject`.